# Is it possible to undefine CMake Xcode settings?

Tags: xcode, cmake

I'm currently trying to use CMake to generate an Xcode project file, but I would like to undefine certain user-defined settings that CMake generates automatically when making an Xcode project. More specifically, I want to undefine `WARNING_CFLAGS` that CMake wants to set for my build targets in Xcode. I've tried the following in my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
set(CMAKE_XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_WARNING_CFLAGS "")
```

However, that has no effect at all. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
set_target_properties(<target> PROPERTIES XCODE_ATTRIBUTE_WARNING_CFLAGS "")
```